# What was the magic/witch thing in The Secret Place?

Tags: the-secret-place

This is about the novel "[The Secret Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Place_(book))" by Tana French.

Some girls in the novel obtained supernatural abilities like lifting objects, Heating rings, Turning lights off and on etc.

But there was no role of those abilities, so what was that? How did they get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely the reaction that the author wanted to get from you. The whole *do they/don't they* theme is something that the author even highlights in her book's '[reader's guide](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/312053/the-secret-place-by-tana-french/9780143127512/readers-guide/)' on the publisher's website as being [intentionally ambiguous](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmbiguousSituation).

> 5. There are episodes of the supernatural throughout the novel. **Do you believe that Holly and her friends had magical powers?** Did the
>      students actually see Chris’s ghost? What was the dark shape that
>      Moran noticed through the doorway?

Adolescent fantasy comes into full relief in this book. Echoing works such as Arthur Miller's The Crucible, the girls are excitable, under extreme psychological stresses,  highly suggestible and prone to seeing fantastical things. They have a late night party where they convince each other that lights are jumping around when they concentrate on them and one girl (Selena) is convinced that she has magical powers and can make things move with the power of her mind but, crucially, **only when other people aren't around to see it.**

> In a bathroom cubicle, she tries whether she can still flicker the
>   lights, whether her silver ring will still spin above her palm. **She
>   does it on her own so the others won’t see her fail and guess why, but
>   everything works perfectly.**

The same group of girls even manage to convince others that they've seen the ghost of Chris Harper and have an episode of [group psychosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folie_%C3%A0_deux).

> ‘And the new one twenty-four hours later, and the next one, and the next? Girls need a safety valve, Detective Conway. Do you recall, a week or so after the incident’ – small snort of laughter from Conway: incident – ‘a group of students claimed to have seen Christopher Harper’s ghost?’
>   ‘In the girls’ jacks,’ Conway said sideways, to me. ‘Fair enough; first place a young fella would go if he was invisible, am I right? A dozen young ones screaming their lungs up, hanging on to each other, shaking. I almost had to do the old slap in the face before they could tell me what was going on. They wanted me to go in with my gun and shoot it. How long’d it take to settle them, in the end? Hours?’
>   ‘After that,’ Miss McKenna said – to me, again – ‘we could, of course, have forbidden any mention of Christopher Harper. And the “ghost” would have reappeared every few days, possibly for months. Instead, we arranged group counselling sessions for all the girls, with emphasis on grief management techniques. And we set up a photograph of Christopher Harper on a small table outside the assembly hall, where students could say a prayer or leave a flower or card. Where they could express their grief in an appropriate, controlled fashion.’
>   **‘Most of them hadn’t even met him,’ Conway told me. ‘They didn’t have any grief to express. Just wanted an excuse to go mental.** They needed a kick up the hole, not a pat on the head and poor-little-you.’

All sensible evidence points to the "powers" not being real.

Comment: Thanks, @Valorum Still, this question remains unanswered:-(. "What was the dark shape that Moran noticed through the doorway?"

Comment: @KishanVaishnav - I suspect it was a long day and a lot of stress.

Comment: But then Conway and Moran discussed this and she told him that they had experienced the same thing 1 year ago.

Comment: @KishanVaishnav - Indeed. And that's the whole point, to make you re-assess your belief about it being a natural phenomenon. To make you uncertain.